# On image hover show the list item

Tags: javascript, jquery

On hover over an image I would like to show the list item. My issue is that I'm not exactly sure how to call only the li I'm hovering using jquery.

HTML

```
<ul class="test">
<li><img></li>
<li class="hidden"><img></li>
<li><img></li>
<li class="hidden"><img></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.test .hidden { display:none; }
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).find(".test li img").hover(function(){
         $(this).find('.test .hidden').show();
      },function(){
         $(this).find('.test .hidden').hide();
      });
});
```

Comment: How can you hover over the image if its parent is hidden? Wouldn't the image be hidden as well?

Comment: This should give a better understanding of my question.

Comment: And I have to add one   comment.  Not sure where you are going, but... don't forget there is no hover event available on mobile devices, and if you are even remotely thinking of a use that a mobile user might be looking at, you might rethink this entire approach....  No offense intended (I've been there myself, ouch.)

Comment: Appreciate your advice, but this is purely for desktop users.

Comment: Still not sure what you want? If the previous `li img` is hovered, show the next `li` or?

Comment: Appreciate the negs, after the fact...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a fiddle for you. Just have a look at it.

```
<ul class="test">
<li><span class="image">Image 1</span></li>
<li class="hidden"><img>showthis</li>
<li><span class="image">Image 2</span></li>
<li class="hidden"><img>showthis</li>
</ul>

.test .hidden { display:none; }

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".test li .image").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).parent('li').next('li').removeClass("hidden");
    });

    $(".test li .image").mouseout(function(){
         $(this).parent('li').next('li').addClass("hidden");
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/swaprks/2zs1sq65/

Comment: That's a no go for me. I'm getting no event firing on mouseover.

Comment: On image hover, he needs to display the list element.

Comment: Even though my initial question confused some, this was closest to what I was going after. Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code in css, without JQUERY:

```
li:hover{ 
    display:block;
}
```

html code:

```
<ul >
<li> test<img src="https://placehold.it/350x150"/></li>
<li>test<img src="https://placehold.it/350x150"/></li>
<li>test<img src="https://placehold.it/350x150"/></li>
</ul>
```

css code:

```
li:hover >img{display:block !important;}
```

[Jsfiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/samane/sq93wt3z/6/)

Comment: This, in my opinion, is the best way to go.

Comment: This doesn't make sense because you can't hover a `li` if it has `display: none`...

Comment: Have you tried this in a jsfiddle or test program?  it doesn't work for me, ref: fiddle address below..

Comment: I've tried both `visibility: hidden`, `visibility: visible` as well as `display: none` and `display: block`  (visibility reserves space in the DOM, `display: none` does not reserve space in the DOM.)   Are you able to provide a functional example?

Comment: Huh, the one with my DNU note in the CSS?? (DNU = Do Not Use) that's a tool I use to quickly kill a CSS class or ID for quick testing purposes....  I can't get that jsfiddle to do anything at all either with or without the DNU note.  Its functionally dead. It is my belief, that in order to fire an event you have to hover over something.

Comment: With that update, yes, I agree.  You mouse over a visible parent, then you can make the child visible.  You can not mouse over nothing and expect to fire an event.  (nothing = `visibility: hidden` or `display: none` element)

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to hover over a hidden item, the other way is pretty easy.

here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sq93wt3z/1/)  (Hint for next time... do this BEFORE asking the question.)

```
(without any CSS at all...)

<ul class="test">test
<li><img src="https://placehold.it/350x150"/></li>
<li><img src="https://placehold.it/350x150"/></li>
<li><img src="https://placehold.it/350x150"/></li>
</ul>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".test li img").hover(function(){
         alert("Hello there.");
         $(this).hide();
      });
});
```

What, exactly what are you trying to accomplish?

Update: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sq93wt3z/4/)   You have to have something to hover over, even if its a few "nonBlankingSpaceCharacters"  Here I'm using the dots for the unordered list. (in fact as I look at this, on that JSfiddle, the `<li>` element has 100% display width, so it catches mouseover events pretty easily.)

```
.test li img{display: none;}
img:hover { outline: dotted red; }

<ul class="test">test
<li><img src="https://placehold.it/350x150"/></li>
<li><img src="https://placehold.it/350x150"/></li>
<li><img src="https://placehold.it/350x150"/></li>
</ul>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".test li").hover(function(){
         //alert("Hello there.");
         $(this).children("img").show();
      });
});
```

One nice reference is [Mozilla Developer Network posting on Hover event.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Ahover)  Look at DropDown Menu description.

Comment: Agree with this solution.